# Dockerfile: reference previously defined ENV in another ENV

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile in which I set some environment variables (for use when I run the container). Some of the environment variables depend on previous environment variables. I want to be DRY and avoid having to hard-code the value of environment variables multiple times, when I could substitute in a variable.

In this simple example, the PYTHONPATH environment variable uses values from the PROJ_DIR environment variable.

```
FROM python:3.8.4

ENV PROJ_DIR=/myproj/ \
    PYTHONPATH=${PROJ_DIR}:${PYTHONPATH}
```

However, when I actually run the container, the PROJ_DIR correctly gets set, but the dependent variable, PYTHONPATH, does not get set.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile . -t test-docker
docker run --rm -it test-docker:latest bash 
root@60fc899899a1:/# export | grep -i proj
declare -x PROJ_DIR="/myproj/"
root@60fc899899a1:/# export | grep -i pythonpath
declare -x PYTHONPATH=":"
```

How do I use previously set environment variables in a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work you would need to spearate out the variables and use multiline assignment.

```
ENV PROJ_DIR /myproj/
ENV PYTHONPATH ${PROJ_DIR}:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Throughout the entire instruction, environment variable substitution will use the same value for each variable. In your case PROJ_DIR is yet to be assigned a value, so it returns empty in PYTHONPATH varaible.

To be more clear, in:

```
ENV x=hello
ENV x=world z=$x
```

`z` will have value *hello* and not *world*.

Due to multiline there will be not be any additonal layers getting created as ENV layers do get squashed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse environment variables that were previously set **outside** but not inside an `ENV`, since all statements in the same `ENV` pick up the value defined before the `ENV` is processed. So you should split it into separate `ENV`s.

```yaml
ENV PROJ_DIR=/myproj/
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PROJ_DIR}:${PYTHONPATH}
```